# Python Selenium press down arrow to dispay all page contents

Tags: python, selenium

I have opened a web page using webdriver (selenium & python). All the items on the page do not load unless I press the space key 8 times or hold the down arrow.

```
driver.get('https://www.some-website.html')
driver.find_element_by_class_name('profiles').click()
```

I have googled for a solution with ActionChains but I am unable to find a solution. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pressing a space would probably just scroll the page to the very bottom which probably triggers loading additional content. What you can do is is to use [`ActionChains()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) to press SPACE 8 times *with a delay*:

```
import time

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
for _ in range(8):
    actions.send_keys(Keys.SPACE).perform()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Or, you may [scroll into view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) of the "footer" element (or something else in the bottom, depending on the particular web-site):

```
footer = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("footer")
for _ in range(8):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", footer)
    time.sleep(1)
```

These are all guesses though, it is difficult to provide a reliable working solution without actually trying them out on the actual webpage you are working with.

Comment: Both your solutions worked perfectly. The PAGE_DOWN version suggested by ayoub also works. Thanks for taking the time to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the PAGE_DOWN key 2 or 3 times

```
import time

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
for _ in range(3):
    actions.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).perform()
    time.sleep(1)
```